# Android - White space on the right and the left of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

When I add element into a layout(in this case a LinearLayout), there is a white space on the two side of the element, but the attribute layout_width is "match_parent". Why?

Here's a screenshot:
http://s32.postimg.org/o4vr8kzbp/device_2016_07_30_001720.png
The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="500dp"
       android:background="@color/blue"
       android:orientation="vertical">


   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cannot help without looking at what you have tried. post the xml file.

Comment: @Nerd Yes , I've posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this lines somewhere on this site and it might be worth checking;

This is possibly because you are using the auto-generated layout files in Android Studio when starting a new project, which by default adds a margin of 64dp to tablet screens (the value found inside values-w820dp\dimens). – PPartisan 6 hours ago

Maybe you should check your layout's parent's layout in the host activity for one more time.

Comment: Ok I found it! I was checking the activity home layout, but there is another layout generated by Android studio, the content_home, which contains  this value. For the material design can this value equals to 0 or there is a mininum padding to insert?

Comment: I just really don't know this issue really. Maybe giving it a go by changing that value and test'-runnging the compilied app on realy devices and plus a quick search on Google could lead you to the informed decision. Fighting! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the root layout does not fill the parent or that the child you are adding has a margin, to know exactly whats going on use the android tool called DDMS or Android Device Monitor (you can launch it from Eclipse or Android Studio) then click on Dump View Hierarchy. This will give you details on the size, padding, margin and other properties of every view on the view hierarchy [image]

Comment: There is a scroll view in another layout generated by Android studio which contains the padding. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You should to check your code, may be you update margins of layout at your classes.

And try to check layouts of home activity, may be they are contains layout_marginLeft(layout_marginStart) and  layout_marginRight(layout_marginEnd).

Also parent layouts may contains any white views on the sides or parameter layout_weight with specific value.